# I have some questions about promises and concurrency in this Codesandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise

I'm new to Javascript and React Javascript and I have this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/promise-hotpink-loader-jscp9?file=/src/App.js).
Open console and watch output..

It's loading like 20 fetch promises into an array and then watching them resolving with a progressbar.

I wonder the following:

- Do the array of fetch promises run in parallell? In the code at `return Array.from(Array(promises)).map(()..` It will do 20 loops and set up a 20 `fetch` but when is the `fetch` started? Do all 20 start in parallell or as soon as possible.
- In the code `PromiseLoader` is using `setInterval(() => {...` with 200 millisecond to "listen" on the promises and report progress as they resolve. Isn't this bulky why not let every `fetch` instead report in with let say "redux", if it's `isFulfilled` `isPending` `isRejected`, would there be some concurrency problem with this approach (JavaScript limitations?).
- This CodeSandbox only focus on showing progress but if one wanted to show all states of the `fetch` promise like pending, rejected and of course the result, and have this propagated into let say a table list, how could this be modified to do that what is there to consider?

I have a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-wu-xi9n7?file=/src/MUITable.jsx) where I try this. It's a filepicker and the file is then cross checked against Firestore in the `fetch` and then displayed in the material-table. But that part is not done jet. It's working but I must create this what I talk aboutand what @trixn talk about -"broadcastUpdate just has to be changed to report back individual promise states,"

Comment: The requests start when `fetch()` is called, which means they already start during the `map()`. You don't need redux to achieve that. `broadcastUpdate` just has to be changed to report back individual promise states, when they change or another callback to pass to `PromiseLoader` has to be defined to receive updates. What have you tried to implement your third point? Also `PromiseLoader` doesn't really have to be a component. It doesn't render anything. It can be refactored to be a hook `usePromiseLoader`.

Comment: @trixn I have tried some code I will try to show in a sandbox

Comment: You may also want to have a look at [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com) which is a great library to handle data fetching. It has a [`useQueries`](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQueries) hook that may be easier to use for your purpose.

Comment: Example using react-query: https://codesandbox.io/s/promise-hotpink-loader-forked-wglgh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-wu-xi9n7?file=/src/MUITable.jsx) where I try this. It's a filepicker and the file is then cross checked against Firestore in the `fetch` and then displayed in the material-table. But that part is not done jet. It's working but I must create this what I talk aboutand what @trixn talk about -"broadcastUpdate just has to be changed to report back individual promise states,"